# Bash: «Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "then")» and «1: eval: Syntax error: "(" unexpected»

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I have a [shell script for updating a project's version automatically on commit](https://github.com/celiavelmar/conventional-pre-commits) that's working perfectly on zsh (on macOS Catalina) and not working on bash (on Ubuntu 20.04).

When running the script, I get the following error:

`Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "then")`

On the following line:

```
if [[ $commit_title =~ (into )([A-Za-z0-9-]+) ]]
then
  merge_branch=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
else
  merge_branch=$main_branch
fi
```

And if I remove the block of code that is using bash rematch I get the following error:

`1: eval: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

I use eval in multiple places, for example:

```
if eval '[[ $current_branch =~ '"^($git_flow_from)$"' ]]' && eval '[[ $merge_branch =~ '"^($git_flow_to)$"' ]]'
then
  echo 'Skipping version update for this merge...'
  exit 0
fi
```

You can see the whole script here for context (I did not include it in the question because it is a bit long): https://github.com/celiavelmar/conventional-pre-commits/blob/master/scripts/update_version.sh

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you're running the script in bash? Note that `/bin/sh` on Ubuntu is `dash`, not `bash`.

Comment: Try checking your script at [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) ... shows problems with fix suggestions, and even suggested improvements.

Comment: @choroba I have `#!/bin/bash` as the first line on my script.

Comment: @CeliaVelasco: And how do you run the script?

Comment: @choroba Ok... I was running the script via `sh ./scripts/...`. With `bash ./scripts/...` it's working perfectly fine. Thank you so much!

Comment: @CeliaVelasco It's generally best not to use either `sh` or `bash` (or whatever) to run scripts, just set the shebang right, add execute permission to the script, and run it with just `./scripts/...` -- this lets the shebang control execution, so you don't have to know which dialect the script is written in. BTW, are those `eval`s really necessary? They look like an opportunity for something to go weirdly wrong.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I used `eval` because some regular expressions include variables that can be configured by the user and after many attempts that was the only way I got it to work.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed thanks to @choroba's comment on my question that I was running the script with `sh` instead of `bash`. This caused the script to run on `dash` on Ubuntu and fail since it uses bash features not available in other shells.